# How to suppress specific warnings in STM32CubeIDE (Eclipse CDT)

Tags: eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to suppress some warnings like "-Wunused-function" and "-Wunused-variable". Normally on other IDEs you can simply add these warnings to a list to avoid them but I can't find where to do this simple thing in STM32CubeIDE (Eclipse CDT).

Answer (score 0):

To add custom assembler/compiler/linker flags such as the ones you want to add, you need to:

1. Right-click the project in the *Project Explorer* view and select *Properties*
2. In the dialog, select *C/C++ Build*>*Settings*
3. Select the *Tool Settings* tab in the panel
4. Select *Miscellaneous* in the right category (assembler, compiler or linker)
5. Add the desired flag to the *Other flags* field

The following picture shows an example of the *-Wl,--fatal-warnings* added to the linker flags:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think I already tried that since I have used Eclipse quite a bit, but it didn't work for some reason that I don't remember, it has been a few months. Nevertheless, I will try again, thank you!